# Utilizing Pain for Nourishment

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, science-fiction

Welcome to the Sanguine Jungle! This scenic location features many beautiful and amazing sights that you just won’t find anywhere else. Carnivorous plants? We got ‘em! Man eating beasts? Hiding in every crack and crevasse with ravenous, blind hunger! Giant winged ape-monsters who literally thrive on causing pain before tearing their prey apart? You literally can’t miss them! So come visit the Sanguine Jungle today, where your pain is our gain!

So know that the advertisement is out of the way, lets get down to business. Due to some evil supernatural shenanigans, every living thing in the Sanguine Jungle derives some sort of nourishment or strength from pain, especially the pain of other creatures. Though that’s probably rather obvious. For this end every creature in this environment has adapted spines, serrated claws, painful venom, and many other natural weapons to increase the pain of prey and potential predators alike. Also, every creature in the Jungle is either strictly carnivorous or omnivorous. Most of this I have worked out well enough but I am a bit at a loss for one important piece of the puzzle.

To be clear it doesn’t have to be that they literally get calories from it or anything like that, but creatures that are better at causing pain in their prey should be larger, stronger, and obviously more dangerous than creatures that aren’t so good at it. Also it has to work on foreign species. For example, a native creature would still gain strength from inflicting pain on a regular human dropped into this hellish landscape. Ideally this method should be technically possible, even if it is extremely unlikely that it would ever occur in a living creature. If it isn’t possible at all then bonus points for creative answers! So to recap, an ideal answer is biologically possible, explains why creatures that are good at causing pain are more biologically successful than ones who aren’t, and could potentially occur naturally even if it’s incredibly unlikely.

Edit: The supernatural shenanigans in play were responsible for mutating that creatures in the jungle so that they crave causing pain in other living things. The creatures themselves don’t use any magic (or very little in some cases). The land was corrupted by supernatural energy that causes pain then uses that pain as fuel.

**Question:** How do these creatures feed on pain?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question *Due to some evil supernatural shenanigans, every living thing in the Sanguine Jungle derives some sort of nourishment or strength from pain,*. Without knowing how your magic system works you're effectively asking us to fill in the details of your world for you.

Comment: The magic system in this case is more in the background, it directed or maybe more accurately “mutated” these creatures toward this end. For the purposes of the question, the processes of “how we got here” is not important. I just want to know if this is physically explainable without significant handwavium.

Comment: You want to know how humans can be magically sustained off pain after entering this environment? See the word magical in the past sentence. Without explaining how your magic works, the best we can do is say, "*magic*". The creative people on this site can make up uncountable numbers of explanations for how magic *could* work in your world but we're not here to build your world for you.

Comment: I see an edit is required. I meant that a creature from this environment gains strength from pain inflicting on anything, including foreign creatures like a human.

Comment: Even if you clarify that it's only creatures withing this environment you'll need to describe your magic system for us to provide meaningful answers.

Comment: VTC as there is nothing in the question that would define a good answer? Each answer would be just as good as another. You need to add more information that would limit the scope of the expected answer to avoid answers based on a range of opinions.

Comment: I've put a small edit, don't know if it helps to prevent close, but I did not see a  clear question at first, I've set it apart. @Nick if you don't like the edit please undo it.. and it would help to have some directions (and clues) for a best answer.

Comment: "every creature...is either strictly carnivorous or omnivorous" - without some dedicated herbivores there isn't a plausible food chain to provide nutrients and energy to the psychic vampires at the top.  Which seems to come back to @sphennings point that this is all inexplicable entropy-defying magic.

Answer (score 1):

### Pheromones

They feed on the pheromones released by their prey. Making the prey scared helps with the release of the pheromones.

Or perhaps they dont actually need the pheromones for nutrition but it is addictive like a drug.

---

From the web (The Guardian website)

*People can unconsciously detect whether someone is stressed or scared by smelling a chemical pheromone released in their sweat, according to researchers who have investigated the underarm secretions of petrified skydivers.
The team found that the smell of fear triggered a heightened response in brain regions associated with fear when inhaled by volunteers in a brain scanner. The research suggests that like many animal species, humans can detect and subconsciously respond to pheromones released by other people.*

Comment: I want to add something based on this part that you wrote: "but creatures that are better at causing pain in their prey should be larger, stronger, and obviously more dangerous than creatures that aren’t so good at it."   Ok, so let us say that the females of the many species in the Sanguine Jungle are the ones addicted to the pheromones and that they get sexually aroused by it. Therefore it is the offspring of the really big scary ones that thrives. The ones that dont inhale pheromones follow their regular mating cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when we see this trope in fiction, there is always the element of *psychic phenomena*. Farscape, Star Trek before it, quite a few others. The trope is unexplained and largely inexplicable.

However, if a civilization/organism/chtulhu/hive of virtual organisms lived in some substrate that allowed access to the real world, they might inflict pain on organisms present in that real world for "entertainment purposes".

This entertainment drives economic progress in their substrate, ultimately increasing their numbers, increasing the computing power that they harness through the substrate, and ultimately making them more powerful.

To the unsophisticated, they could appear to be some monster or demon from another plane of reality that is psychically feeding off of pain.

But for a simple biological organism to feed off pain is silly and you need to use handwavium.

Comment: In the book Those who hunt the night by Barbara Hambly, the vampire actually needs to feed on the psychic death of the prey.

Comment: @mcbecker Yeh, and there have to be dozens/hundreds of other examples to boot. But I'm not venturing into TV Tropes to find a list for you, I've got stuff to get done this month.

Answer (score 1):

### Noise from pain

If something is in pain. It will yell and scream for help, the sound could generate a chemical similar to Oxytocin, but with the ability to convert into glucose after being released and reacted with blood, Increasing blood sugar and cellular respiration. Leaving the animals (or plants) in a vicious cycle on keeping their selves alive with this chemical, while also using it up indefinitely until the day they die.